# In Objective-C, what is the difference between a Factory Method and a Convenience Initializer?

Tags: objective-c, constructor, initialization, factory

So every object has the default initializer method, `-init`

If you need your object to be instantiated with properties, you would write something like
`-initWithProperty1:(Property1*)prop1 andProperty2:(Property2*)prop2`

This would be called like this:
`[[SomeClass alloc]initWithProperty1:(Property1*)prop1 andProperty2:(Property2*)prop2]`

I always thought this was called a factory method (is that correct?)

But then I stumbled across this SO question:
[How to write an Objective-C convenience constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046073/how-to-write-an-objective-c-convenience-constructor)

Where it looks like a "convenience constructor" is the same thing as a factory method?  But maybe a convenience constructor specifically uses a class method as the initializer?  so it seems like a convenience constructor would look like this:
`+someClassWithProperty1:(Property1*)prop1 andProperty2:(Property2*)prop2` and would be called like:
`[SomeClass someClassWithProperty1:(Property1*)prop1 andProperty2:(Property2*)prop2];`

Does anybody know what the terminology should actually be?  Are the two terms, "Factory Method" and "Convenience Constructor" the same thing in this context?

Comment: I would call the `initWithProperty` method the "convenience initializer", and the `someClassWithProperty` method the "factory method". But that's just based on general knowledge. I don't recall seeing either term being used in the Apple docs.

Comment: Yeah I can't find anything concrete in the docs.  A lot of sources have conflicting information-- which is why I want to say the terms are interchangable

Comment: Yup, that's the way the English language works. A word means whatever you want it to mean, as long as other people agree with your definition :)

Comment: Haha well when I was committing a change, I wasn't sure which term to put in the commit message.  I want to be consistent with other people's definition.  Also if I read one or the other, I want to make sure I know exactly what they're talking about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Convenience constructor" used to be the official term that Apple used for this concept; then they started calling it a ["factory method"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ObjectCreation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH39-SW4). The nature of it hasn't changed: it's [a *class* method that creates an instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5988016/603977). `initWith...` is not a factory method.

"Convenience **initializer**" is a term from Swift, not ObjC.

The "designated initializer" is unrelated except insofar as this creation method, like any other*, must eventually call through to it.

---

*With the exception of `initWithCoder:`

Comment: Thanks Josh, so in your ObjC do you prefer instantiating objects w/ a factory method or a designated initializer?

Comment: Personally, under ARC, I almost always write a convenience constructor.